# Is there a database which tags the "high/low" sense of comparative adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

For example, “faster” is “high” (speed) whereas slower is “low” (speed). Similarly, "longer" is "high" and "shorter" aligns with "low".

Comment: I don't believe this criterion is well-defined. For example, which of "wet" and "dry" is high, and which is low?

Comment: @ColinFine in line with cold, hot, solid and fluid, I'd argue naively that dry is low, but of course that's problematic. A cold gas is said to be low in entropy but that is colloquially called a state of higher order, though depending on the enclosing system, in which the gas may reach a warmer state of equilibrium, the latter would be said to have higher order.

Comment: With semantic word vectors a la wordnet, more than two dimensions are necessary.

Comment: @vectory: yes, more than two dimensions are necessary; but this is not even about the number of dimensions, but about the direction or sense within a single dimension.